# whitelist limited ec2 IPs with third party service provider

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2

We have an application running on ec2 which talks to a third party service. The third party service provider requires us to give them 13 IPs for whitelisting. My limited understanding of ec2 is that we cannot define IP range for ec2 instances. So given the requirement from our third party provider, is it possible to continue to use ec2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provision Elastic IPs and assign them to instances. These IPs remain yours to use until you release them back into Amazon's pool of addresses.

Do note that provisioning an EIP without using it costs you a small amount of money per hour. If you only have a handful of instances, don't go provisioning 13 EIPs and leaving most of them inactive.